# How to send Google token via different header instead of Authorization - Cloud Run

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run

If I deploy my service in (cloud run) as no-allow-unauthenticated, I can add a user with `cloud run invoker` role to secure the API. Then user can login to gcloud and set the token in the authorization header to access the service.

My question here is, can I send the Google authorization token via a different header instead of authorization?

The reason why I am using google token is to protect staging(development) env to only allow access to the dev team. My Spring Boot app doesn't need any protection under google platform as it has its own oAuth mechanism - authorization header is being used by spring boot.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking if can you send the Google authorization token (identity token) via a different header instead of **authorization**? There is work being implemented to support **proxy-authorization**, but the last time I tested this (fall 2021), it was not working. The SDKs are starting to mention this. Edit your question to be more specific on what you are asking.

Comment: yes, I found this page based on your comment, but as you said, Proxy-Authorization doesn't work: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_proxy-authorization_header

Comment: Just tested, it should work only with IAP because it doesn't work if you invoke a Cloud Run service directly.

Comment: @Nav do you use another OAuth2 provider, or do you use Spring Security (for authorization) in addition of Cloud Run security?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, yes, I have my own auth service, and it's integrated into all cloud run services (spring boots) as OAuth. So, technically I don't need google security. I am just trying to protect cloud runs for my development environment. Only developers should access the APIs.

Comment: but, if it's protected by OAuth, your OAuth, why using Cloud Run security? in dev or Prod, it's the same logic: even if the API is available, you can use it.

Comment: using application-level security is not a good idea for the development env, as the team is developing the app, it could be broken or it is not desired to set up the auth service with the developer's profile. I am looking for a replacement for a VPN.

Comment: @Nav, I found quite a similar case to your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857416/test-oauth-application-in-google-cloud-run-when-authorization-header-is-already?rq=1, which might be helpful and its related documentation link: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/signed-headers-howto

Comment: I found the better solution here is to switch to VPN/Bastion Host to make private tunnel to the GCP for private access rather than dealing with IAP. My microservices have their own oAuth and auth service to its better to not mess up with GCP security features.

Comment: @Nav, "Post your solution as a stackoverflow answer"

Answer (score 0):

After a lot time spent, I decided to configure spring boots to deal with another Authorization header name. I left `Authorization` for GCP.